# Slow Rendering Times

Tags: rendering

I have what I consider to be an above average computer. Specs Gforce GTX 780ti. 16GB Memory Intel i7 - 4790k 4.00GHz. However although it would appear to be fast when rendering the blenchmark test render, turning in a respectable 1 min 12 secs. When it came to rendering my first ever tutorial off the Blender Guru site. (The one with the Doughnuts..you may have seen it). With samples set to around 128 blender reports it would take over 4 hours to render out. Surely this can't be right. So it's out of desperation that I'm turning to anyone out there who can help me out as I haven't got a clue why this should be the case. Would therefor appreciate any help on the matter please.

Thanks
Foxtrot

Comment: Please provide blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so we can see settings. Also what OS are you using? Which Blender version?

Comment: Hi LukeD, thanks for the quick response, however after looking around this site I managed to find a solution to the problem. Which was a simple matter of unchecking 'square sampling' under the sampling tab. In saying that, although  everything renders quickly now, I cannot say that the rendered result looks any different whether I set the samples from 128 -8000. I can still see jaggies around the cup and my doughnuts don't seem that sharp. I guess I have a lot to learn. Do you have any Idea why my render isn't razor sharp? - Thanks mate

Comment: @Foxtrot Please add some screenshots so I be able to give you some advice. It's really hard to tell why if I don't know what you have and what you want.

Comment: Hi Luke, I'm not sure how to do that. I'll have to google it or something. In the meantime I think my problem (apart from me being stupid that is) is that the subsurf modifier was set to render subdivisions to 2. So my model was low poly to begin with.  Sorry about that..

Comment: If I remember correctly, the doughnut tutorial uses a fluid sim for the topping. So what comes to mind here is the resolution of the fluid. Have you tried cranking the _Final_ resolution up (it will take longer to bake). Also, _Subdivisions_ under _Fluid Boundary_ may help, but that too will increase baking time.

Comment: Hi Duane, not in this case I think. It only uses proportionate something or other cant remember the exact name. Basically you copy the top half of the doughnut create a separate object and add a solidify modifier. Then tweek it with proportional editing. So the mesh has a subsurf on it. However the sprinkles are low poly particles.

Comment: I've only just started using blender its all very new to me. I have to say though that the interface could be a lot better. I have used 3ds max in the past and that was much simpler as I recall. More logically laid out if you know what I mean. Still Blender can hold it's own just takes a bit of getting used too. Just out of interest how many samples would you use in a final render. Thanks